# Accessing Files from User Device using Flutter or Python

Tags: python, flutter, file

I am making a music player with flutter so, I wanna to ask how to access all the files of a particular extension ( mp3, wav ) with it's details in Flutter or if not in Flutter then Python to play those music files with details like song name, author name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004220/how-to-get-all-mp3-files-from-internal-as-well-as-external-storage-in-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you can basically do:

```
import os 
files=os.listdir("/path/to/folder or empty for working folder")
for file in files:
    if file.endswith("extension but for you .mp3/wav"):
        print(file)
```

By doing this you can get the file name with `.mp3/wav` extension.
Otherwise you can use `glob` library:

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob("*.mp3 or /path/*.mp3"):
    print(file)
```

By using `glob` also output is same!

For getting artists and other metadata you can use [`songdetails`](https://github.com/Ciantic/songdetails) library:

```
import glob
import songdetails

for file in glob.glob("*.mp3 or /path/*.mp3"):
    song = songdetails.scan(file)
    if song is not None:
        print(song)
        print(song.artist)
        print(song.duration)
```

For more information visit [songdetails](https://github.com/Ciantic/songdetails) github page.

If this answer helps you to solve your problem then, don't forget to mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using flutter with native app, then you can use path_provider and the dart File to get all you want in Android. However, ios is more like a sandbox, so it is hard to get what u want.