# FLUTTER EPUB READER

Tags: flutter, mobile, download, epub

How to display the list of books that are in **epub** format in our mobile and allowing us to read the selected book using a **flutter** framework.

Comment: This is a very broad question. It would be helpful to know what your code is and where you are facing problem. You may want to see this question for listing specific files types from the storage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49399958/how-to-get-all-pdf-files-from-internal-as-well-as-external-storage-in-flutter . Also, check out the `epub` plugin for flutter https://pub.dev/packages/epub

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [epub_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/epub_viewer) plugin to display `epub` files and you can use a database to store the books before displaying in your app.
This [open source project](https://github.com/JideGuru/FlutterEbookApp) might help you

Comment: I have seen this. I think you had used the API for fetching books. If I have the books in my system and keep it in the assets folder then how to display the books and read them.

Comment: Is there any article to help me to use this app ? The docs is not that clear to me :(

Answer (score 0):

You should try https://pub.dev/packages/vocsy_epub_viewer
It's not customizable, but it has good features and UI.