# Loading files from external downloads folder for use in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I am creating a book reading app for android using flutter. The app downloads books from a specific web page and stores them in the phone, then it allows the user to read the pdf files inside the app. We decided that it would be best to store the files inside android's downloads folder. Up to here everything works.

The problem comes when trying to display the pdf in the app. I can't access the pdfs directly from said folder and couldn't find any information about fetching files from external directories. All plugins I tried for reading pdfs had an option to read "from assets" but I asume this is only for files inside the app's asset folder. When trying to use this option with the uri of the already dowloaded file it can't find it.

Is it possible to read the files directly or is it requiered to load them first into the app? If so, how exactly?

EDIT:

Thanks for any help but already solved it using the open_file plugin

Comment: This is of course specific to the plugin. Which plugin(s) have you tried?

Comment: Please give an example of such a path for a pdf file. How comes you use a path and not an uri? You are on Android Q?

Comment: @blackapps yeah sorry, I meant URI and put path by mistake

Comment: @Thomas The last two I tried where flutter_pdfview and native_pdf_view

Comment: Please give an example of such an uri. The value of uri.toString() please. You are on Android Q?

Comment: Please see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49399958/how-to-get-all-pdf-files-from-internal-as-well-as-external-storage-in-flutter

Comment: Thanks for the help but I managed to solve it, I edited the question